# Makefile which will zip file

Tags: c#, .net, makefile

I have calculator which I made in C# and I want to make a `Makefile` which will zip all files. I know how to zip like just one file `.c` or `.h` but I don´t know how to zip like the whole folder.Can anyone help me?

```
WindowsFormsApplication2


and in this folder are : ClassLibrary1, WindowsFormsApplication2, WindowsFormsApplication2.sln ....
```

Comment: What does [tag:c#] has to do with this? Furthermore can you please show the desired behavior using an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I zip a folder in MSBuild?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917803/how-do-i-zip-a-folder-in-msbuild)

Comment: Do you want to zip the folder (with its contents)? Or do you want to zip each file in the file individually?